# Not able to pick lastest created date folder in all cases

Tags: file, directory, powershell-ise

I am having multiple vertical folders and in each vertical folder there are multiple builds,  I want to pick latest build files for each vertical.
Picking build number according to configs pattern. Below piece of code is working correctly in for some verticals, but not for all, Here vertical is just a folder name.

```
{
    # Pick Build folder containing config BuildPattern
    $buildFolders = (((Get-ChildItem $capLocation -Recurse)| 
                    Sort CreatedDate | 
                    Where-Object {$_.name.Contains($buildpattern)}))

    # Extract file for each Vertical as per config value
    foreach($vert in $vertical)
    {
      # Pick latest vertical folder under latest build
      $verticalBuildLocation = ($buildFolders | 
                               Sort CreatedDate |
                               Where-Object {$_.Fullname.Contains($vert)})[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: `CreatedDate` does not exist! maybe you mean `CreationTime` ?

Comment: I repeat: the property is `CreationTime`. :)

Comment: Thanks I am using below code and its working now.{  $verticalFolder = (Get-ChildItem $capLocation | Where-Object {$_.Fullname.Contains($vert)})
          $verticalBuildLocation = (get-childitem $verticalFolder.FullName -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name.Contains($buildpattern)}| sort @{Expression={$_.CreationTime}; Ascending=$false})[0]
         }

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code is working
{ 
 $verticalFolder = (Get-ChildItem $capLocation | Where-Object {$*.Fullname.Contains($vert)})
          $verticalBuildLocation = (get-childitem $verticalFolder.FullName -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {$*.name.Contains($buildpattern)}| sort @{Expression={$_.CreationTime}; Ascending=$false})[0]

}